# How to define the return type / OutputType of a function

Tags: powershell

Why is the following changing type?

```
function SomeFunction($SomeParameter){
    return $SomeParameter
}
```

I guess I need to set a return type, but how?

An example is using:

```
$NewFolder=Join-Path $CurrentFolder -ChildPath $FolderName
$Tmp=SomeFunction($NewFolder)
```

Now `$Tmp` is an array and not just a path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is per "design". PowerShell will return an array in chunks so that it can be forwarded the PowerShell pipeline.

Example:

```
 SomeFunction -SomeParameter @(1,2,3,4) | Where-Object { $_ -gt 2 }
```

Without this behavior pipelining the output of the function to another function/cmdlet won't be possible.

If you want to return an array you can change to code to:

```
 function SomeFunction($SomeParameter){
    <#
     # Through the unary operator we can return an array with one entry.
     # This entry contains the original array.
     #>
    ,$SomeParameter
}
```

Another option would be the use of `@()` when at the calling side:

```
function SomeFunction($SomeParameter){
    # return to pipelin
    $SomeParameter
}

$array = @(SomeFunction -SomeParameter 1,2,3,4)
```

There is also this [reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/6yogs2/functions_that_return_arrays/) explaining the behavior in more detail.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 12):

While [this answer explains the behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57478847/712649) you're seeing, here I will attempt to answer the actual question: **how to declare the expected output type of a function**!

You do so by adding an `[OutputType]` attribute to the `param()` block of your function - so the first thing you'll want to do is to skip the C#-style param list and declare a proper `param` block instead:

```
function SomeFunction
{
    param($SomeParameter)

    return $SomeParameter
}
```

Now we just need to add the `[OutputType]` attribute decorator:

```
function SomeFunction
{
    [OutputType([string])]
    param($SomeParameter)

    return $SomeParameter
}
```

since we're just returning the parameter argument value as-is in this example, we should play nice and make sure it's actually also a string:

```
function SomeFunction
{
    [OutputType([string])]
    param(
        [string]$SomeParameter
    )

    return $SomeParameter
}
```

Worth noting that `[OutputType()]` makes *no guarantees* as to the type of objects emitted during execution, it's simply a way for the author of a function to indicate the *intended* output type.

Read more about `[OutputType]` in the [`about_Functions_OutputTypeAttribute` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_outputtypeattribute?view=powershell-6)

Comment: So one doesn't necessarily need to go read about the `OutputTypeAttribute` (though I do recommend checking it out, there are good nuggets of knowledge to be had!), all this attribute allows you to do is declare what your function is _expected_ to return, but it in no way _enforces_ that the value(s) returned by your function are of the declared type. So, IMO, this doesn't _really_ address the OP's question. The _real_ answer is that there is no way to specify that a function returns a specific type. (Note, I said function and not Cmdlet--the two are very different, the latter written in C#.)

Comment: @fourpastmidnight My answer already covers that ("Worth noting that `[OutputType()]` makes no guarantees as to the type of objects emitted during execution, it's simply a way for the author of a function to indicate the intended output type."), but you're more than welcome to submit another answer if you feel the existing ones are insufficient :)

Comment: Hmm, I see what you stated about "no guarantees", it's just, at the top, you made it sound like you were specifying a return type. I wanted to make it clear you are not specifying a return type, just _declaring_ that the function _should_ return the indicated type. I was just trying to clarify that this is only a _hint_, to users and (more properly) to PowerShell for IntelliSense, but that's all. Your answer, otherwise, is superb! In fact, I upvoted it because it is entirely correct (save that minor quibble I have ;) )