# How to create a type to specify as the `OutputType`?

Tags: powershell, types, powershell-7.3

The information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_outputtypeattribute?view=powershell-7.3 is helpful. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57478857/447901 is helpful. But, the only examples given are predefined PowerShell types. I need to define my own object, not just a simple `[string]`.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [OutputType ???]
)

[PSCustomObject]@{
    FirstName = 'Bill'
    LastName = 'Smith'
}
```

I tried creating a `class`, but could not get that to work.

```
class Person {
    [string]$FirstName
    [string]$LastName
}
```

Comment: You have `[OutputType ???]` inside the param block? It should be outside together with the cmdletbinding decoration

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, ok, I will put it outside. The real question is what should replace `???` to represent the `[PSCustomObject]` that will be output?

Comment: I don't understand why you have a person class yet you want to output a pscustomobject. Doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

If you're declaring a `Person` then doing `[OutputType([pscustomobject])]` makes no sense, you should be returning an instance of that class instead. Declaring that your output type will be `pscustomobject` is the same as not having any declared output type at all since these objects can have any structure.

```
class Person {
    [string] $FirstName
    [string] $LastName
}

function Test {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([Person])]
    param (
        $FirstName,
        $LastName
    )

    [Person]@{
        FirstName = 'Bill'
        LastName  = 'Smith'
    }
}
```

Much better to make the promise to return an instance of your class, then the completers would work properly:

[image: thing]

Comment: Can this be done without a `function` as the question asks? Can a plain .ps1 script produce and `OutputType` of the user's creation? Would `Add-Type` be of any use?

Comment: @lit if the class is loaded beforehand I dont see why not. `Add-Type` has nothing to do with this, a PowerShell class is compiled at runtime

Comment: How would the class be loaded beforehand? Built-in types such as `[string]` and `[FileInfo]` are loaded beforehand. What needs to be done to get this `[Person]` type loaded beforehand? Must this come from an `Assembly`? It seems that the `Assembly` would need to be loaded into the session before the PowerShell instance starts interpreting the .ps1 script. I have not yet found an example on the net. Can you suggest an example?

Comment: @lit the graceful way to do it is with a module, else, one of the workarounds named in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837447/powershell-unable-to-find-type-when-using-ps-5-classes